# Hide element on one page only

Tags: css

> body.943 .ish-button-small {display:none;}

I want to hide the class ".ish-button-small" on the page with the id 943.
Keep in mind only on that page. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: nvm, misread what you were asking.

Comment: then should be `body#943 .ish-button-small `

Comment: Is `943` id attribute of some element or querystring parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
body#943 .ish-button-small {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#943 .ish-button-small {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't just use CSS for that, this should work with Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("943") != -1) {
    $("#.ish-button-small").hide();
  }
});
```

Checks if the URL contains 943 and if it does it hides the element with the class .ish-button-small